# Perhaps vs probably

Tags: word-usage, usage

To express stronger uncertainty what word is correct, Perhaps or probably?

> Perhaps I was wrong
>
> Probably you were right

Comment: "Perhaps* refers to some *possibility*, and something that is *probable* is more likely than something that is *possible*.

Answer (score 2):

With the example you give, they express equal uncertainty. How you say it changes the meaning a lot.

> *PERhaps I was wrong* = I was not wrong
>
> *Perhaps I WAS wrong* = I might have been wrong
>
> *Probably you were riGHT?* = You might have been right
>
> *Probably you WERE right* = You were right

In general, however, **perhaps** is more uncertain than **probably**.

(I'd say **perhaps** is 50% certain and **probably** is 90% certain, but others might disagree.)